# computer won't turn on but plugging in ethernet lights up switch

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have an issue where my computer/motherboard won't turn on, I am not sure if it is fried but when the ethernet is plugged in the light on the switch turns on, meaning that some kind of current is passing through my machine.

The machine was turning on but while plugged into an extension cord it turned off, and will not turn back on. Possible surge? Possible low rated extension cord? I don't know the gauge of the cord but it has been used for high powered lawn equipment outdoors for many years.

Is there a way to determine if my mobo is fried without switching power supplies? When I turn on and off the PSU, my lights flickr, which they do whenever something somewhat high powered is turned on. How to proceed?

Would the components on the board like the memory and gpu be fried too

Comment: Have you tried unplugging the power supply for a few seconds? I've had this happen after a power outage, several times. The motherboard will refuse to boot until I unplug it for at least 15 seconds or so.

Comment: @Bort tried that, nothing different

Comment: power supply fuse or other fuses blown?  Yes there are still things like this around.

Comment: It does sound like a power supply issue but the only way to be certain is to try it with a psu you know works.

Comment: @Col yeah the motherboard turns on with a different power supply of the same model. Is there anything I can do with the current one? Could the extension cable have fried it or would that have been a surge that fried it. The computer was on for like 5 minutes before just shutting off and not coming back on again

Comment: It's hard to say, most likely is a spike on the power to your house or a simple hardware failure. Cheap PSUs are renowned for going pop at the drop of a hat. I'd always use at least a surge protector or a ups if you're in an area with really bad power.